# Python np.gradient in Mathematica

Tags: syntax, python

Very quick and dirty question. I'm trying to write a program written in python into mathematica and there is a section that uses the gradient function in the numpty python library, `np.gradient` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html). In the python script it just finds the gradient of a list of numbers.

Is there a Mathematica equivalent? I see there is a `Grad` function but it seems to be used for functions rather than a list of numbers, or I just don't know how to use it.

Here's the python script snippet, `v` is a list of numbers, so is `z_list` as are all the `betas`, `int_phi` is a function that uses the betas to produce, you guessed it, a list of numbers. Also in python, you have to split functions up into real and imaginary to integrate them, that's one point to mathematica I guess lol

```
for j in range(len(v)):
print(j)
phi_r = np.empty(len(z_list))
phi_i = np.empty(len(z_list))

for i in range(len(z_list)):
    z = z_list[i]
    b_21=beta21[j]
    b_12=beta12[j] #dunne schicht mos2 grenzt an luft
    b_23=beta23[j] #intercal mos2 grem-nzt an mos2
    a = quad(lambda q: np.real(int_phi(q,z)), 0, np.inf)[0] (* integrate over pre- 
    defined function 0->inf*)
    phi_r[i] = a
    a = quad(lambda q: np.imag(int_phi(q,z)), 0, np.inf)[0]
    phi_i[i] = a

#calculate derivatives
phi_r_ = np.gradient(phi_r,z_list)
phi_i_ = np.gradient(phi_i,z_list)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The post above is a replicate of MATLAB's gradient, but the usage and effect is quite similar to that of numpy's. Or you want to replicate the behavior of numpy.gradient **exactly**?

Comment: Well I would want a function that produces the same numbers as that of numpty, whether it does that using a different process, so be it! I'll have a look at the above link, one sec

Thank you sir/ma'am

Comment: Yah, that helps, thank you!!